# CalledFromWrongThreadException when trying Access member of Activity in other thread in Android application

Tags: java, android, textbox

I have tried to put my problem in below pseudo code:

```
public class something extends Activity {

    // some buttons and text view declaration
    public TextView textViewSomethingStatus;

    on create() {
            textViewSomethingStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something);
            //Here at one point i have stated thread
             new specialThread().start();
    }

    // some methods


    class specialThreads extends Thread {

         public void run() {
          //after performing some task.
          textViewSomethingStatus.setText("hello world");//This gives me crash
          }    
     }
}
```

When I want to update text in text box from another class I get a crash. How do I do this? As in Java we cannot extend multiple classes.

**Edit :**

**E/AndroidRuntime(  605): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public void run() {



//check some status of something here

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 textViewSomethingStatus.setText("hello world");//This will not give you crash now 

            }
        })
```

Why so ?

Read about the Android threading concept. And don't forget to correct the `onCreate()` typo: you wrote method name `oncreate()` instead of `onCreate()`; and yes `setContentView(layout_id)` is also missing in `onCreate()`

Comment: No. this will post your runnable to UI thread, so whenever UI thread will be free, it will execute this runnable . alternatively you can use AsyncTask or handler, but as a newbie move ahead with this simple runnable and keep enjoying your android learning.

Comment: no i want thread...this threads checks the some status of something and change its result on UI and it must run in background as always

Comment: ofcourse you will do that inside run() of specialThreads. only UI related stuff like textview text change should go inside runOnUiThread runnable. editing answer for you .

Comment: okey thanks man...i have made another methods as your code and used in my thread and now its works like charm....!!!!

Comment: as title of question is not very suitable, so please update it as "CalledFromWrongThreadException when trying Access member of Activity in other thread in Android application". so that answer can be useful for other users in future.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `specialThreads` is within the `something` class, you can access it. That shouldn't be the one throwing the error(because if you couldn't access it there, then it would have shown an compilation error itself).

The error is because, you forgot to set your content view in your `onCreate()`, before initializing your `TextView`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This is to fix the android related error. For threading issues, which you're likely to face post this change, refer the other answers posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is the 'main' Thread, you can not update your UI from another one. There are ways to do that on Android though. I would use a Handler [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Also unless you specify what "crash" is - what error you get, it is really hard to tell.

Comment: @Mr.32 the error is exactly what I suspected. You can not update the UI from another custom Thread, that is not allowed in Android. You have to use runOnUiThread method or use AsyncTask or a Handler. I suggested a Handler because I use it more often. There a lot of examples on the web on how to use one. basically you heen to create a Handler with new in onCreate for example, then do a postDelayed for example of your runnable.

Answer (score 1):

without the stacktrace it is hard to determine the correct error but I think you have to run the thread on your UI-Thread:
Try that example code:

```
something.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                             textViewSomethingStatus.setText("hello world");//
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the problem which you are in earlier too.So here's it:

---

**Note**:
(if you just donot like the suggestion try making everything you want to use as static.ie.classes,variables and on and on)

---

### The best thing you can do

You should use [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and there's a good [tutorial over here.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Few of the simple things you need to take care of ...

- make a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`.(in the Activity itself)

  ```
    private class RecvrPClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

  /**
   * 
   */
  public RecvrPClass() {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see
   * android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
   * android.content.Intent)
   */
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // Toast.makeText(arg0, "GOT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  //fetch whatver you need to do here ;refresh();

  }}
  ```
- Make an instance of it and register it

  ```
   private BroadcastReceiver _refreshReceiver = new RecvrPClass();

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SOME DESCRIPTION");

      this.registerReceiver(_refreshReceiver, filter);
  ```
- `SendBroadcast`s using `Intents` wherever you need to fire/call the implementation

  ```
   Intent inBiz = new Intent("SOME DESCRIPTION");
          sendBroadcast(inBiz);
  ```